# Why does echo not change the %ERRORLEVEL%?

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

The `%ERRORLEVEL%` contains the status code of the previously run command. If the command completed successfully the code will be 0, otherwise it will be something else. So then consider the following:

```
> cd foo #there is no foo
The system cannot find the path specified. #expected
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1 #expected
> echo %ERRORLEVEL%
1 #unexpected
```

Why isn't the second `echo` returning `0`? I would expect that since the first echo completed successfully the `%ERRORLEVEL%` would be changed to `0` and the second `echo` would print `0`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20770788/why-the-return-value-of-echo-is-always-1

Comment: Not all commands reset the ERRORLEVEL when successful. `echo` is among those which do not. See [Which cmd.exe internal commands clear the ERRORLEVEL to 0 upon success?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34968021).

Answer (score 0):

It's because only a bunch of commands returns a `ERRORLEVEL`, as someone said here's a list: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34968009/which-cmd-exe-internal-commands-clear-the-errorlevel-to-0-upon-success/34968021#34968021

I dont see why `ECHO` would return an ERRORLEVEL since there is now way it errors.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts
of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become
invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ECHO can fail.
If you have several PCs updating a single log file

```
echo something >> \\someserver\somepath\some.log
```

then the ECHO command can fail quite often.
I have used:

```
set /a rand=%random% %%59 + 1
ping 127.0.0.1 -n %rand% >NUL
```

to try and space out the PCs but that does not always work and there are PCs that never update the log file. I wish that ECHO did show an error level, that way I could pause again and update the log again if it failed.

Comment: This is not `echo` failing but the redirection operation `>>` failing.