# How to detect when a redirect operation of a windows cmd echo fails

Tags: command-line, batch, cmd.exe

Is there a way to detect if a echo redirection into a file, f.e.

```
echo asdf > C:\nonexistingdirectory\asdf
```

fails?

`ERRORLEVEL` doesn't seem to be set.

Is checking if the file exists afterwards the only option?

Also see:  ***Why does `echo` not change the `%ERRORLEVEL%`?*** [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1778861/1739258)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Conditional Execution: **`&& succeeds`** and **`|| fails`**](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

```bash
>nul 2>&1 (echo/ asdf >C:\nonexistingdirectory\asdf) && echo/ yEp! || echo/ nOp!
```

---

Read more:

- [Conditional Execution](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)

  - [`||`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) and [`&&`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html)
- [Commands Redirection](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php)

  - `|`, `<`, `>`, `2>`, etc.